# Jquery - fire click event only on the top top layer and not on both

Tags: jquery, events

When click on the `Child`, `Parent` and `Child` are firing the `alert`.

Ho can I make only the `Child` to Alert when I click on it?

```
<div id="Parent" style="width:300px;height:100px;border:solid 1px red;">
    Parent
    <div id="Child" style="width:300px;height:50px;border:solid 1px green;">
        Child
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Child").click(function(){alert('child')})
    $("#Parent").click(function(){alert('Parent')})
})
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WAYgL/
If you click in this example on the `Child` both of the alerts will be fired how can I prevent from the `Parent` to alert

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call the [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method of the event object:

```
$("#Child").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('child');
});
```

That stops the event from bubbling up the DOM tree (which is how DOM events behave by default).

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)